# Disable TSQL script check?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

lets say I have a script like that:

*if(some condition)
begin
    select somecolumn from sometable
end*

Lets say, that "somecolumn" does not exist and the condition is not true, which means the select is **NOT** executed. Even though the select would not be executed, the script is not valid, Management Studio complains about the missing column "somecolumn".

Question: Can I somehow disable this sort of check so that the script is executed and since the if is not true, it will never notice that the column is missing?

Thanks :-)

Comment: There is something seriously wrong with your design if you have to worry about whether a column exists or not.

Answer (score 5):

Use dynamic SQL

```
if(some condition)
begin
    exec ('select somecolumn from sometable') --or sp_executesql
end
```

It actually makes no sense to run this because of what SQL is. It's not executed line by line: the whole batch is parsed etc in one go and the error is generated here, before anything actually runs in the sense you mean. This is by design...

Comment: not 100%
This code works for me:
IF OBJECT_ID('Reports.dbo.RecordsTable') IS NULL
However other approaches with just plain parameter strings to indicate table1 or 2 fail.

However the dynamic sql trick always works, but is a bit annoying of course.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a procedure that references a table that does not exist however that is the only exception to the rule. From the BOL:

> Deferred name resolution can only be
>   used when you reference nonexistent
>   table objects. All other objects must
>   exist at the time the stored procedure
>   is created. For example, when you
>   reference an existing table in a
>   stored procedure you cannot list
>   nonexistent columns for that table.

Beyond using dynamic SQL, there is no means to reference non-existent columns in a stored procedure.